# is possible to do more actions at the same time?

Tags: python, asynchronous, process

is possible to create a program (for example python) that can do more things at the same time? For example :

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(30)
    #do something that require some seconds. time.sleep just for example
```

but at the same time do something other, like check  the clock and if the time is 12:00 print "it's 12:00".

is that possible ?

Do the Operating sistems do something similar this maybe?

Comment: If most of the tasks are I/O related, then perhaps look into `asyncio` or `trio`

Comment: thanks. So it is possible, but why? The CPU can do only 1 thing at the same time (if has just 1 core), am i wrong?

Comment: @Jokey Computers often have multiple CPUs. And IO-bound tasks aren't entirely reliant on the CPU.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: Also you can use sybprocess module to begin several .py (but you can use .pyw to get rid of the console) scripts in one program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible.

The [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) packages, among others, can be used to do multiple things at the same time.

Generally, multithreading is used when the actions that you want to do in tandem are "IO-bound", like waiting on sockets or a disk write. Multiprocessing is used when the actions are "CPU-bound", like doing calculations.

The need for the two comes about because CPython (the most common implementation) uses a global lock: the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). The lock prevents multiple instructions from being carried out at the same time, even on different threads. If you use another implementation that doesn't have a GIL, multithreading can be used instead for both cases. Multiprocessing is just used to get around the lock, as the doc pages mention.

Comment: Note this is true only in the context of python due to GIL

Comment: @yaccz Added a note about CPython.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this and there are different ways you can do this:

Multiprocessing, Multithreading, Parallel processing. For this, there are python modules like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and [joblib](https://github.com/joblib/joblib).

Joblib is a relatively higher level module than the multiprocessing module. So if you are starting to explore these concepts, then it is recommended to start with multiprocessing. This way you will get to know the intricate details of multiprocessing.

Multiprocessing: The availability of more than one processor per system, which can execute several set of instructions in parallel is called as multiprocessing.

Multithreading: A process is divided into several different sub-processes called as threads, which has its own path of execution. This concept is called as multithreading.

Within multiprocessing, you have various ways in which multiple tasks within a single program can be deployed. You can use "Pooling" which offers a convenient means of parallelizing the execution of a function across multiple input values, distributing the input data across processes (data parallelism).

And then there is "map" which basicaally applies function to every item of iterable and returns a list of the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. And then are many more ways of assigning multiple tasks either by using all the cores of the system.

There are other functions within the multiprocessing that allow you complete control of how a "task" or "tasks" are executed. You can read them in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Notice that I used the word "parallel" within the "multiprocessing" module. But understand that parallel processing and multiprocessing are different things.

**Multiprocessing** A processing technique in which multiple processors or multiple processing cores in a single computer each work on a different job.

**Parallel processing** A processing technique in which multiple processors or multiple processing cores in a single computer work together to complete one job more quickly.

Can multithreading work on a single core computer - Yes!